# Weblogic JMS Queue in cluster with multiple instance of application

Tags: java, jms, weblogic

I have Weblogic and JMS Queue. Also i developing application which will be deployed to multiple servers (cluster), so there would be multiple instance of this application. Applications will listen JMS queue and do some stuff with messages.

My question is: When i send a message in JMS Queue, and application instance A take this message, will application instance B retrieve this message also? So i need that all my applications will receive message from JMS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When i send a message in JMS Queue, and application instance A take this message, will application instance B retrieve this message also? So i need that all my applications will receive message from JMS.

Depends on what JMS interface you're using: in case of *Queue* only one consumer will get the message, in case with using *Topic* you could deliver message to multiple subscribers. So, in your case you should choose Topic over Queue.
Take a look [at Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/jms/design_best_practices.html#wp1061024) and also [at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9529220/how-to-select-topic-vs-queue) for more details.